# Why GC Execution happens frequently and takes too long on my Ruby Rails with REE deployment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, garbage-collection, passenger

I have a Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 application deployed on Apache 2.x with mod_ruby (REE). I collect performance statistics with NewRelic and I see that GC Execution happens too often and takes too much time.

What shall I look at to improve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of articles I came across recently that I think help explain this.

[One](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/uncategorized/rails-3-performance-abysmal-to-good-to-great/) - Rails 3 Performance: Abysmal to Good to Great

[Two](http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/documentation.html#_garbage_collector_and_object_space) - Garbage collector and object space